# How to stop ScrollView to move automatically

Tags: android, layout, android-scrollview

In the **layout.xml** below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ScrollView
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/category_layout_top"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    >
<ImageView
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/category_Image_View"/>

</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:id="@+id/category_linearlayout">
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:singleLine="true"
 android:id="@+id/category_textView"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/category_recycler_view"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"

    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/def_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Whenever the respective activity is started, the ScrollView ends up showing the last items of the RecyclerView automatically. How to prevent that?**

I tried to remove the android:descendantFocuabiity="beforeDescendants"  from the Framelayout containing ImageView just in case,to see if it works, and it didn't.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: in my opinion, instead of use scroollview then you can addheader to recyleView as use with old listview.

Comment: please explain in detail.

Comment: i mean : you can move all view and layout on top of RecyleView into a combined view which wil be added into RecycleView header. so when you scroll listview and combined view will be scroll. unessery use scrollview

Comment: Yeah, I can do that too. But using scrollview would be easy.

Comment: Yes but scollview will conflic with scroll event of recyleview or lisview